# Change caption label delimiter with babel french in memoir but without caption package?

Tags: captions, memoir, babel-french

The following `memoir` document includes the `french` option to `babel`.

Is it possible — *without* using the `caption` package — to force use of the caption label delimiter that I specify with `\captiondelim`?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[french,main=english]{babel}

\captionstyle[\centering]{}
\captionnamefont{\sffamily}
\captiondelim{\textsf{.\,}} % note delimiter!
\indentcaption{0pt}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\noindent\hrulefill

{\changecaptionwidth\captionwidth{3in}%
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\framebox[8.25cm][c]{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}
\caption{A very long caption. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah}    
\end{figure}
}
\normalcaptionwidth

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\framebox[10cm][c]{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}
\caption{A very short caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As the output shows, the caption delimiter has been changed from my specified period to a colon, and I know this is because `babel` has the `french` option.

[image: wrong caption delimiter with babel french in memoir doc]

I am aware of the `caption` package, which could be used to correct that. However, I do not know whether, or how, `caption` would allow on-the-fly change of the caption width as is possible with `memoir`'s built-in commands `\changecaptionwidth` and `\normalcaptionwidth`.

Comment: Adding `\frenchsetup{CustomiseFigTabCaptions=true}
\renewcommand*{\CaptionSeparator}{\textsf{.\,}}` to the preamble should give the desired result.

Comment: @leandriis: That works, thank you! But why then does just `\renewcommand{\CaptionSeparator}{\textsf{.\,}}` *not* work?

Comment: @leandris: this is because the main language is English. `\renewcommand{\CaptionSeparator}{.\,}`  works out of the box when the main language is French, otherwise you have to force the flag `CustomiseFigTabCaptions` to true to take `\CaptionSeparator` into account.

Answer (score 1):

This is an oversight of mine: babel-french is ignoring your redefinition of `\captiondelim{}`. The same occurs with koma-script and beamer classes.

It is fixed in version 3.5i that I will push to CTAN tonight or tomorrow. Thanks for reporting.

Please note that `\captiondelim{.\,}` is enough as you already chose `\sffamily` as `\captionnamefont`.