# Why does \captiondelim cause error with babel-french?

Tags: captions, memoir, babel-french

The MWE below causes the error:

```
./caption-err.tex:9: Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 \begin{document}
                    
? q
OK, entering \batchmode...
Runaway argument?
{.\ }\ifx \reserved@a \@empty \let \check@icl \@empty \let \check@icr \ETC.
./caption-err.tex:9: Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.9 \begin{document}
                    
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text....
```

How can it be fixed?

The error does *not* occur if `french` is not used as a `babel` option.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,ngerman,main=english]{babel}

\captionnamefont{\sffamily}
\captiondelim{\textsf{.\ }}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\framebox[15in][c]{\rule{0pt}{1in}}
\caption{A figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Related:**

[Change caption label delimiter with babel french in memoir but without caption package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550479/change-caption-label-delimiter-with-babel-french-in-memoir-but-without-caption-p)

Answer (score 6):

The new version of french.ldf contains a `\edef\FB@capsep{\@contdelim}`. This is not a good idea as it as no control over the content of `\@contdelim` and so can't be sure that it is expandable. This should be at least `\protected@edef\FB@capsep{\@contdelim}`. Report this to the author.

With the `\edef` the `\textsf` in your definition breaks. So a way to avoid the error is to use `\captiondelim{.\ }` instead.

Comment: I have reported this to the `babel-french` author.

Answer (score 3):

Until `french.ldf` is updated to fix the glitch, you can make `\@contdelim` robust under `\edef`.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,ngerman,main=english]{babel}

\captionnamefont{\sffamily}
\captiondelim{\textsf{.\ }}
\makeatletter
\protected\edef\@contdelim{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@contdelim}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\framebox[5in][c]{\rule{0pt}{1in}}
\caption{A figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

The previous version of `french.ldf`, 2020/04/18 v3.5h, had

```latex
1541      \ifFBCustomiseFigTabCaptions
1542        \ifFB@koma
1543          \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{\CaptionSeparator}%
1544        \fi
1545        \@ifclassloaded{memoir}%
1546           {\captiondelim{\CaptionSeparator}}{}%
1547        \@ifclassloaded{beamer}%
1548           {\defbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{FBcustom}{%
1549                \CaptionSeparator}%
1550            \setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[FBcustom]}{}%
1551      \else
1552        \ifFB@koma
1553          \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{{\autospace@beforeFDP : }}%
1554        \fi
1555        \@ifclassloaded{memoir}%
1556           {\captiondelim{{\autospace@beforeFDP : }}%
1557           }{}%
1558        \@ifclassloaded{beamer}%
1559           {\defbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{FBcolon}{%
1560                 {\autospace@beforeFDP : }}%
1561            \setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[FBcolon]%
1562           }{}%
1563      \fi
```

The new one, 2020/06/30 v3.5i, has reworked the code above

```latex
1551      \@ifclassloaded{memoir}%
1552         {\edef\FB@capsep{\@contdelim}\edef\FB@std@capsep{: }%
1553          \ifx\FB@capsep\FB@std@capsep
1554            \ifFBCustomiseFigTabCaptions
1555              \captiondelim{\CaptionSeparator}%
1556            \else
1557              \captiondelim{{\autospace@beforeFDP : }}%
1558            \fi
1559          \fi}{}%
```

This is disputable under many respects. There is no reason for doing

```
\edef\FB@std@capsep{: }
```

when `\def` is more than sufficient. But the main error is in the previous declaration that should be

```
\let\FB@capsep\@contdelim
```

as the code wants to compare the *meaning* of `\@contdelim` with a standard. Well, the user might do

```
\newcommand{\mycaptiondelim}{: }
\captiondelim{\mycaptiondelim}
```

and the test performed by `french.ldf` would return false (with the proposed fix). But it *should* return false, because the user ***surely has*** a reason for the indirection (for instance, they want to avoid `french.ldf` taking precedence over their preferences).

As Ulrike Fischer states in her answer, the `\edef` is conceptually wrong, because nothing makes certain that `\@contdelim` will only contain `\edef`-safe tokens.

Comment: I disagree with your statement "There is no reason for doing `\edef\FB@std@capsep{: }` when `\def` is more than sufficient".  Doing what you suggest `\let\FB@capsep\@contdelim` and `\def\FB@std@capsep{: }` would make the test `\ifx\FB@capsep\FB@std@capsep` /always/ FALSE as it occurs AtBeginDocument : the colon's  catcode has changed in between!  My concern is to get a proper space before the colon in French with the standard definition of `\@contdelim`.

Comment: @DanielFlipo Maybe you have some reasons to, I can't see one. Anyway, `\edef` is the wrong tool. What has the category code of the colon to do? It's frozen at definition time and `\edef` doesn't change this.

Comment: Indeed `\edef` is wrong but Ulrike's suggestion looks fine for me.

Comment: I know that the category code is frozen at definition time.  That's precisely my point: the colon has catcode 13 when I define `\FB@std@capsep` (AtBeginDocument) but 12 in memoir's original definition of `\@contdelim`, thus the test `\ifx\FB@capsep\FB@std@capsep` returns FALSE anytime, even if `\@contdelim` is unchanged.  Defining `\FB@std@capsep` /before/ babel-french activates the colon would work and avoid using `\protected@edef`, that's probably what i will do.

Comment: @DanielFlipo No, the definition of `\FB@std@capsep` uses a token list that has already been absorbed when `french.ldf` is loaded, so it will have the catcode it had at that time, which I presume is 12.